# JSON Parsing Converted Error

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse JSON from a website and display it in a ListView. However, when I run my program, I get a JSON parsing error (shown below):

[image: JSON parsing error: Value]

How can I fix this?

My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "https://www.netdata.com/JSON/9c9cc5eb";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hissetList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hissetList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetHisse().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetHisse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray hisseler = jsonObj.getJSONArray("array");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 3; i <6; i++) {
                        JSONObject c = hisseler.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("ID");
                        String name = c.getString("dc_HisseKodu");
                      //  String email = c.getString("dc_WebAdresi");
                    //    String address = c.getString("dc_Adresi");
                       // String gender = c.getString("dc_BagimsizDenetimKurulusu");
                        //String mobile = c.getString("dc_Telefon");
                        // Phone node is JSON Object


                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> hisse = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        hisse.put("id", id);
                        hisse.put("name", name);
                      //  hisse.put("email", email);
                    //    hisse.put("mobile", mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        hissetList.add(hisse);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, hissetList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "id"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                     R.id.mobile});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post complete error message

Comment: Please Post the full exception Text instead of a Screenshot.

Comment: Link bottom of page     Json parsing error: Value

Comment: AND Json object here  [link](https://www.netdata.com/JSON/9c9cc5eb)

Comment: Pictures are not a substitute for text.  We cannot copy and paste from a picture, the search engine cannot match words in a picture, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response received is in the form of JSONArray not JSONObject.
instead of:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

use this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Gson and www.jsonschema2pojo.org , see this tutorial https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no a json array named "array". You change code like this

```
JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
for(int i = 0; i<jsonObj.length(); i++){
     JSONObject c = jsonObj .getJSONObject(i);
     ......
}
```